# Fetching DOM with help of pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
$("#popupShapes ul li a").click(function () {
     //some code
});
```

I want to convert it to pure javascript.

This not works because getElementById expects to single id:

```
document.getElementById('popupShapes ul li a')
```

How can I convert the jQuery code above to JavaScript?

Comment: Use `querySelector` to select single element, `querySelectorAll` for multiple elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `querySelector` instead, which accepts a selector string:

```
document.querySelector("#popupShapes ul li a").addEventListener('click', function () {
     //some code
});
```

If you have multiple matching elements, use `querySelectorAll` instead:

```
for (const a of document.querySelectorAll("#popupShapes ul li a")) {
  a.addEventListener('click', function () {
     //some code
  });
}
```

You can also use event delegation instead, but this will sometimes result in *different behavior* than your original code:

```
document.querySelector('#popupShapes').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (!e.target.matches('#popupShapes ul li a')) return;
  // some code
});
```

Comment: What if multiple matches are expected, isn't that supposed to be `querySelectorAll()`?

Comment: There could be multiple anchor tags. Use `qSAll`.

Comment: or better: delegate to parent element

Comment: Please do not add an EventListener to all links

Comment: @mplungjan : what if `<a>` nodes should be treated somehow different from it's siblings?

Comment: @mplungjan That's exactly the same thing that jQuery is doing with `$("#popupShapes ul li a").click`

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov see my answer

Comment: *'...That's exactly the same thing'* it looks, like it's not, as `.click()` is a shorthand to [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler), which *'...Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements'*

Comment: @CertainPerformance Can you think of a different behaviour when delegating, I cannot

Comment: @mplungjan What do you mean, different? I'm pretty sure the `.matches` checks we're doing is almost exactly the same sort of thing jQuery is doing with `.on('click', selector, fn)`

Comment: I quote you: _You can also use event delegation instead, but this will sometimes result in *different behavior* than your original code_

Comment: @mplungjan Ah, that part - I'm just referring to the usual delegation vs not delegation differences. Eg, dynamically added elements will result in the listener body running if delegation is used (listener attached to parent), but not if `$(child).on('click', fn)` / `child.addEventListener`is used. Similarly, assigning to the `innerHTML` of a container will remove listeners on its children, but won't affect a delegated listener attached to the container.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#popupShapes ul li a").click(function () {
  //some code
});
```

I would consider delegation:

```js
document.getElementById("popupShapes").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.matches('#popupShapes ul li a')) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(tgt.href)
  } else console.log(tgt.tagName,"not interesting click")
})
```

```css
#popupShapes {
  background-color: teal; padding:1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="popupShapes">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="x1">X1</a></li>
    <li><a href="x2">X2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a href="z1">z1</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is it single event listener outweighs multiple, despite of requiring more code and getting (theoretically) triggered unnecessarily (even for a simple tag/parent tag check)?

Comment: I do not have time to find documentation but there should be performance considerations and a static parent listener makes it much safer to add and remove children which might not be garbage collected if there were still listeners attached to each

Comment: doesn't do the same, yours is `#popupShapes li > a`

Comment: @Kaiido updated to use .matches which seems to be well supported now

Answer (score 0):

You would have written in this way.

```
const nav = document.querySelectorAll('#popupShapes li a')

nav.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      console.log('hi', e);
    });
});
```

Comment: That is identical to the accepted answer except for the loop method

Comment: Yes, Agree to your point. But it looks more clear and easy to understand.

Comment: Except the nodelist needs to be cast to array for forEach in IE